# How could I bake the movements of two seperate objects parented to the same armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I'm currently attempting to bake the object movement of two separate door objects that I rigged with constraints. What I would like to do is bake the rotation and location of both doors so that I can export the model as a rig in a separate game engine.

[image: The door objects are parented to the armature with each weighted to their respective bones.]

I wanted to know how I could bake the door object animations down to the bones.
I'm using Blender 4.0